# Will a nest loop help in parsing results

Tags: python-3.6, boto3

I am trying to pull information from two different dictionaries. (excuse me because I am literally hacking to understand.)

I have a for loop that gives me the vmname. I have another for loop that gives me the other information like 'replicationid'.

I could be doing a very huge assumption here but hey ill start there.  what I want to do it to integrate for loop 1 and for loop 2. as so  the results are like this, is it even possible?

initial output of for loop1 which I can get:
vma
vmb
vmc

initial output of for loop2 which I can get:
replication job 1
replication job 2
replication job 3

desired results is:

vma 
replication job 1
vmb
replication job 2
vmc 
replication job 3

```
def get_replication_job_status():
    sms = boto3.client('sms')
    resp = sms.get_replication_jobs()
    #print(resp)

    things = [(cl['replicationJobId'], cl['serverId']) for cl in 
    resp['replicationJobList']]
    thangs = [cl['vmServer'] for cl in resp['replicationJobList']]

    for i  in thangs:
        print()
        print("this is vm " + (i['vmName']))
        print("this is the vm location " + (i['vmPath']))
        print("this is the vm address, " +(str(i['vmServerAddress'])))
        for j in things:
            print("The Replication ID is : " +(str(j[0])))
```

again I want:
vma 
replication job 1
vmb
replication job 2
vmc 
replication job 3

im am getting:

vma
replication job 1
replication job 2
replication job 3
vmb
replication job 1
replication job 2
replication job 3
..
..
..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that your lists both have the same length, then what you need is python built-in [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
for thing, thang in zip(things, thangs):
    print()
    print(thing)
    print(thang)
```

But if one of the lists is longer then another then [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) will crop both lists to have the same length as the shortest, for example:

```
>>> for i, j in zip(range(3), range(5)):
...    print(i, j)
...
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
```

**UPD:**

You can also unpack your tuples right in `for` loop definition, so each item (they are 2-tuples) in `things` list gets saved to two variables:

```
for (replicationJobId, serverId), thang in zip(things, thangs):
    print()
    print(replicationJobId)
    print(serverId)
    print(thang)
```

**UPD 2:**

Why do you split `resp` into to two lists?

```
def get_replication_job_status():
    sms = boto3.client('sms')
    resp = sms.get_replication_jobs()
    #print(resp)

    for replication_job in resp['replicationJobList']:
        vm_server = replication_job['vmServer']

        print()
        print("this is vm:", vm_server['vmName'])
        print("this is the vm location:", vm_server['vmPath'])
        print("this is the vm address:", vm_server['vmServerAddress'])
        print("The Replication ID is :", replication_job['replicationJobId'])
```

Comment: ok so what you have given me is perfect.  however, I think I need to think this out more. what I thought  it would do may not be exact. but your info was spot on... I do have one additional question.   These give the error  " TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"     how can I make them work?       `print("this is vm " + (i['vmName'])) `

Comment: its because your `things` list is actually a list of tuples, you have to access tuple item  and then do something with it: `print("this is vm " + (i[0]['vmName']))` or `print("this is vm " + (i[1]['vmName']))`

Comment: I updated answer to show another way of working with tuples inside of loop

Comment: ok.. thank you for the answers.. really much appreciated. I am  new to the army in regards to python..so I need to try these out to understand... thank you all again...

Comment: To answer your question...merely because I have no idea what I am doing. I am just learning. clearly. not very well it appears... thanks much :)